# How to add Twitter, Yahoo, Windows live to my Online accounts?

Tags: 64-bit, 17.04, online-accounts, twitter, yahoo

Ubuntu noob here. I have a fresh install of 17.04, 64 bit. My online account settings only has Google, Flickr and Facebook, image attached. I saw [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/accounts-provider-not-available.html) that it is possible to have Twitter, Yahoo and Windows Live to my online accounts. Can someone share steps on how to get that done?

[Online accounts only has Google, Flickr, Facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmILQ.png)

Comment: I don't believe that they support Twitter/Yahoo/Windows Live accounts any more.

Comment: Oh, ok. I hope you're wrong, though :)

Comment: I *might* be wrong... *anything* is possible... :-)

Comment: Twitter - Install corebird. Yahoo - from dash find  'online account'. For windows live - if you want to config email user Thunderbird.